# TestNG: How to include test groups that are in 2 groups (AND filter)

Tags: java, testing, testng, suite

I want to be as flexible as possible with my test suites - I want to be able to:

- run all tests by priority (p1, p2...) - this is easy
- run all tests by module (module1, module2...) - this is easy
- run tests that are a specific priority and specific module - I can't figure out

I have some tests thusly:

```
@Test(groups = {"p1", "module1"})
public void p1module1() {
    System.out.println("p1module1");
}
@Test(groups = {"p2", "module1"})
public void p2module1() {
    System.out.println("p2module1");
}
@Test(groups = {"p1", "module2"})
public void p1module2() {
    System.out.println("p1module2");
}
@Test(groups = {"p2", "module2"})
public void p2module2() {
    System.out.println("p2module2");
}
```

But if I do something like this

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="qa-selenium">
    <test name="My Suite">
        <groups>
            <run>
                <include name="p1"/>
                <include name="module1"/>
            </run>
        </groups>
        <packages>
            <package name="com.mycompany.qa.selenium.*"/>
        </packages>
    </test>
</suite>
```

the includes are treated like an OR, but I want an AND.  In this case I want to create a suite that ONLY executes p1module1()

I realize I could use tons of excludes - in this example

```
<exclude name="p2"/>
<exclude name="module2"/>
```

but I really want to avoid this.  Is there a way to do this, preferably without metaprogramming?

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="qa-selenium">
    <test name="My Suite">
        <groups>
            <define name="functest">
                <include name="p1"/>
                <include name="p2" />
                <include name="module1"/>
                <include name="module2"/>
            </define>
            <define name="all">
                <include name="functest" />
            </define>
            <run>
                <include name="all"/>
            </run>
        </groups>
        <packages>
            <package name="your_package_name" />
        </packages>
    </test>
</suite>
```

You can try above in order to run test with all possible combination.

The above xml group gives me output in the following manner (Which takes the all possible combination).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use first part of include name common and then use it in include name to execute all the tests as below

Test groups as below

```
@Test(groups = {"a-p1", "a-module1"})
public void p1module1() {
    System.out.println("p1module1");
}
@Test(groups = {"b-p2", "b-module1"})
public void p2module1() {
    System.out.println("p2module1");
}
@Test(groups = {"c-p1", "c-module2"})
public void p1module2() {
    System.out.println("p1module2");
}
@Test(groups = {"d-p2", "d-module2"})
public void p2module2() {
    System.out.println("p2module2");
}
```

Suite xml will look likes below

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="qa-selenium">
    <test name="My Suite">
        <groups>
            <run>
                <include name="a.*"/>
                <include name="b.*"/>
                <include name="c.*"/>
                <include name="d.*"/>
            </run>
        </groups>
        <packages>
            <package name="com.mycompany.qa.selenium.*"/>
        </packages>
    </test>
</suite>
```

In the above xml 
`<include name="a.*"/>` will execute the tests, which are having tagging with `"a-p1", "a-module1"`

No need to define separate include names for P1 and module, `enter code here`same works for others, it will treated like AND not OR, Let me know if its correct answer of your question